# Prevent Linux from accessing some partitions in a Dual Boot system

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, restricted-access

How can I prevent Ubuntu 15.10 from accessing some of the partitions on my dual boot (with Windows 10) to prevent possible data corruption or loss when I'm out experimenting with dangerous commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you have to edit your `\etc\fstab` in Linux and remove the entry/entries mounting the partitions you don't want mounted.

Since they're sorted by UUID, you'll want to find out said UUID's for the partitions. `sudo blkid -L` will list all disks by UUID, like so:

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="727cac18-044b-4504-87f1-a5aefa774bda" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdb: UUID="467c4aa9-963d-4467-8cd0-d58caaacaff4" TYPE="ext4"
```

However, you may still see Windows partitions listed in your file manager - they're not mounted, but will be automatically if you click the entry.

You can hide these partitions:

- In Gnome or Ubuntu Unity (and possibly MATE and XFCE desktops) start the `gnome-disks` program.
- Select your hard drive in the devices list and select the Windows partition (should be listed as an NTFS partition) in the Volumes list.
- Click the gear icon to open the context menu and select "edit mount options". Turn off "Automatic Mount Options" and deselect (or leave it deselected) the options "Mount at startup" and "Show in user interface".
- The entries should no longer show up in the file manager sidebar.

Comment: Thank you so much, Second method worked for me very well!!